# jQuery Corner+Gradient

Tags: jquery, gradient

I have one div element `.box`
It's width is 200px and height is 300px

First I want to make it 's corners round. I do it with following:
`$('.box').corner('round 10px');`

Then I want to add gradient to it. SO it will have rounded corners + gradient. I try following:

```
$('.box').gradient({ topcolor: '#000000', bottomcolor: '#ffffff', horizontal: false, opacity: 40});
```

I get kinda what I want but gradient applies to all box and gradient goes over rounded corners.

I tried to do gradient first then corner, but still same thing.

How can I add gradient + corner to .box and make it look good?

Comment: I'm assuming you're using this? http://malsup.com/jquery/corner/ It helps to specify if this concerns a plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can save yourself some time and use CSS 3?

http://www.css3.info/preview/rounded-border/

Answer (score 0):

For gradient you can also use css3 as described in the following code generator

http://gradients.glrzad.com/